# Removing rows in a pandas DataFrame where the row contains a string present in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I know how to remove rows from a single-column ('From') pandas DataFrame where the row contains a string e.g given `df` and `somestring`:

```
df = df[~df.From.str.contains(someString)]
```

Now I wish to do something similar, but this time I wish to remove any rows that contain a string that is in any element of another **list**. Were I not using pandas, I would use `for` and the `if ... not ... in` approach. But how do I take advantage of pandas' own functionality to achieve this? Given the list of items to remove *ignorethese*, extracted from a file of comma-separated strings *EMAILS_TO_IGNORE*, I tried:

```
with open(EMAILS_TO_IGNORE) as emails:
        ignorethese = emails.read().split(', ')
        df = df[~df.From.isin(ignorethese)]
```

Am I convoluting matters by first decomposing the file into a list? Given that it is a plain text file of comma-separated values, can I bypass this with something simpler?

Comment: the above attempt actually appears to remove a single row, but (i) I cannot tell which row it removed and (ii) it should have removed many more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains) supports regular expression , you can create a regex from your list of emails to ignore by using `|` to `OR` them , and then use that in `contains` . Example -

```
df[~df.From.str.contains('|'.join(ignorethese))]
```

Demo -

```
In [109]: df
Out[109]:
                                         From
0         Grey Caulfu <grey.caulfu@ymail.com>
1  Deren Torculas <deren.e.torcs87@gmail.com>
2    Charlto Youna <youna.charlto4@yahoo.com>

In [110]: ignorelist = ['grey.caulfu@ymail.com','deren.e.torcs87@gmail.com']

In [111]: ignorere = '|'.join(ignorelist)

In [112]: df[~df.From.str.contains(ignorere)]
Out[112]:
                                       From
2  Charlto Youna <youna.charlto4@yahoo.com>
```

---

Please note, as mentioned in [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains) it uses [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) .

Comment: Once again, inspired outside-the-box thinking and an elegant solution. Thanks.